# Calculation over each row from a CSV - file with Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, dataframe

I want to do a calculation over each row from  csv-file in Python.

This is the loaddataa File:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def loadData(relativPath):
    files = os.listdir(relativPath)
    path = os.path.abspath(relativPath)
    datas = list()
    for file in files:
        absPath = path + "/" + file
        print(absPath)
        data = pd.read_csv(absPath)
        datas.append(data)
    return datas
```

These were my first steps:

```
import math as m
import loaddataa as ld    

dataListStride = ld.loadData("../Data/Fabienne")
    indexStrideData = 1
    strideData = dataListStride[indexStrideData]

def horizontal(yAngle, yAcceleration, xAcceleration):
    a = (m.cos(yAngle)*yAcceleration)-(m.sin(yAngle)*xAcceleration)
    return a

resultsHorizontal = list()

for i in range (len(strideData)):
    strideData_yAngle = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 2]
    strideData_xAcceleration = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 4]
    strideData_yAcceleration = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 5]
    ......
    ......
```

In the for - loop I don't know how to go on. The csv - file consists of 9 columns and 150 row. For the calculation I just need column 2, 4 and 5. The calculation with the formula in `def horizontal` shall be executed over each row, so that in the end I have 150 values. I hope it's clear what I want to do.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I suggest looking at the pandas ```apply``` method.

Comment: You can use the [`apply(func, axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method of a `DataFrame` to run a `func` on each row and get an output array of the computed values - this doesn't use a for loop (and thus can be faster for larger data sets).  But if you want to do the for loop (which totally works), what @KD2020 said looks good.

Comment: Thank you. It works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Call the `horizontal()` function in each cycle and add the result to your list using `resultsHorizontal.append()`.

Code:

```
resultsHorizontal = list()

for i in range (len(strideData)):
    strideData_yAngle = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 2]
    strideData_xAcceleration = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 4]
    strideData_yAcceleration = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 5]
    resultsHorizontal.append(horizontal(strideData_yAngle, strideData_yAcceleration, strideData_xAcceleration))
```